# How to make a popup screen when we click on certain text

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

I am working on Dealership website.I am New to Jquery and HTML.
Actually the problem is i have webpage 
http://prospectingdesk.com/demo/index.html
In this Page You can a Quote which moves up and down 
If you click that on you will get a popup window.

And If you go to NewVehicle page in that page there will be so many car list

My requirement is if i click on that Vin Number which appears in the Each car list it will navigate to Next page.But Before that i need to get a Popup window same as a which appeared in Homepage.

THe problem is my Manager told not touch the body of the code.
The new code which we are creating for the popup will be added only in the Header part it seems.

That quote code must be Dynamic .
If i copy the code the paste in any other website the quote must work

Please help me out how to do this friends.

Answer (score -1):

Can you more clarify this. As per my understanding you need to get that element through id or class and then attach click event and write anything you want. 
Let's assume Quote button have id 'quoteBtn' then your code will be like this.

```
var quoteBtn = document.getElementById('quoteBtn');
quoteBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    /*code for pop up open goes here*/
}, true);
```

Comment: Hi ,Thank you for your reply. Actually I have Quotebutton Id = qutton_upload. My problem is i need to create a quote window if i click on any car box before it naviagate to next page. For Each car the code is given in between the div and id seems like vehicle_1,Vehicle_2......like goes on.